# Replace value in field automatically (auto-correct?)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I'd like to replace occurrences found in Column A (cells A2:A200) so that if I enter `2`/`02`/`002` or `343` or `98`/`098` it auto-replaces it with `UKD002`/`UKD343`/`UKD098`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

From rev.

> I'd like to replace occurences found in Column A (Cell A2:A200) so that if I enter 2/02/002 or 343 or 98/098 it auto-replaces it with UKD002/UKD343/UKD098.

To replace a value automatically (just after it was typed) on Google Sheets use an `onEdit`, simple or installable, Google Apps Script triggers.

Example:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var autoreplace = {
     2/02/002:'UKD002',
     343:'UKD343',
     98/098:'UKD098'
  }    
  if(autoreplace[e.value]){
    e.range.getCell(1,1).setValue(autoreplace[e.value]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend putting the keys in quotes, like: `'2/02/002':'UKD002'`.

Answer (score -1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C$2:$C, QUERY({
 IF(LEN(A2:A)=1, "UKD00"&A2:A,
 IF(LEN(A2:A)=2, "UKD0"&A2:A,
 IF(LEN(A2:A)=3, "UKD"&A2:A, A2:A)))}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''"), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SB9HuUTKo0M-BEIgIJP44wbMkqc3QodZPzN7OBvgfRo/edit#gid=1190026423)**